# Was Ludwig von Mises a holocaust survivor?

Tags: world-war-two, europe, nazism, political-economy

Von Mises left Europe to avoid the Nazis. Does that make him a Holocaust Survivor?

Comment: Why is [Wikipedia's](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Holocaust_survivors&ved=2ahUKEwiftPa9mb3jAhXnQd8KHZugBykQFjACegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw0KdVNiLeP8bvnGu56AXGBc&cshid=1563409359371) answer not sufficient?

Comment: Is this question "What is the definition of a holocaust survivor"? I'm not entirely sure definitions of terms are on topic here.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Wiki article on von Mises doesn't really make it clear if he was directly persecuted by Nazis or their collaborants (as per the definition you linked). As far as I can tell, he wasn't, but if he was - that would make him a survivor.

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends on semantics, but I would say not really, at least **not in the strict sense**.

[This article](https://www.haaretz.com/1.4781806) from Haaretz gives the following as a standard definition shared by relevant experts:

> Any Jew who lived for any period of time in a country that was ruled by the Nazis or their allies is called a Holocaust survivor

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_von_Mises) von Mises was Jewish but lived in Austria only until 1934. This means left for Switzerland before the former [Austrian Republic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Austrian_Republic) was annexed by Nazi Germany in 1938.

Comment: You might want to add that von Mises left Austria on his own accord, due to being offered a position at the Graduate Institute of International Studies in Geneva, as opposed to losing his position due to pressure from Nazi collaborants in Austria. The latter would make him a Holocaust survivor by the US Holocaust Memorial Museum or Yad Vashem definitions of such.